# Karate and Selenium into same Test Automation Framework

Tags: selenium, cucumber, karate

Good Day !
I recently got to know about Karate Framework and I have been using Rest assured for these while to do API testing . 
On looking the Simplicity of Karate over Rest Assured to write tests for API ,would like to switch over to Karate and implement the same .
Tried sample Karate for API tests and it works but now i want to how can i customize my Test Automation framework to have API with Karate and Cucumber for Selenium UI together .

**Problem statement:**
For Karate and Selenium Runner class are different .
For Karate->Karate.runner and Selenium with Cucumber-> Cucumber.runner 
Tried Karate.runner to run for Cucumber Selenium cases but not possible .
and Cucumber obviously we cant run Karate Tests .

**So i would like to know** 
1.can i have someway to have two runner class in my single test automation repository  and point Karate for API and Cucumber for Selenium.
2.Can i use Selenium with Karate runner or other way around to achieve the same

**PS**: I am aware if i change my Karate to Rest assured i can still go with Cucumber runner common for both . But i would like to include Karate with my existing Cucumber scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

This is the recommended approach with Karate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233301/143475

There are many teams using this approach and even adding JDBC calls into the mix: [In Karate how we can collaboratively work along with BA to automate business scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47795762/143475)