# How to use both Karate and Selenium to write an end to end test case using Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, karate

Can we run part of Selenium and Karate together? I need to invoke a SOAP service, capture a value from the SOAP response and then pass that value in GUI, and run the GUI test using Selenium.
So- how can we create a single Test Runner- which can include @Runwith- for both- Cucumber.class and Karate.class- 
To write a Scenario in a feature file something like this-
Scenario: soap 1.1
    Given request
    """
    
    
      
        
          2
          3
        
      
    
    """
    When soap action 'http://tempuri.org/Add'
    Then status 200
    And match /Envelope/Body/AddResponse/AddResult == 5
    And print 'response: ', response
    Then user logs in to the GUI app
    And passes value of "variable" from the response in field X

Answer (score 0):

[Karate can replace Selenium now](https://hackernoon.com/the-world-needs-an-alternative-to-selenium-so-we-built-one-zrk3j3nyr), you can use Karate for your entire end-to-end flow. Pay attention to point (9).

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233301/143475